# Highlight or color the Text value in tabular/grid report using wildcard search filter in tableau dashboard

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

We have wildcard search text filter in tableau grid report and it should Highlight/color the Text value in tableau grid report which we are entering on wildcard search text filter in tabular Report/Dashboard

Any Solution or functionalities or workaround to  Highlight/color the Text value in tableau grid report which we are entering on wildcard search text filter in tabular Report/Dashboard